# how can add class in UL when rollover and active in LI

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok what i want to do when rollover LI that time add class on ul and when it will active same to add class UL bellow like html structure

see my menu [image]

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Rentals</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Company</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

so when rollover and active then code will be like

```
<ul class="active-1st">
  <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a></li>
....
</ul>
```

same when 2nd li rollover and active then

```
 <ul class="active-2nd">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
              <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a></li>
    ....
    </ul>
```

the reason behind is. my navigation menu have background image that will effect whole UL area. that's why i want to change css by rollover and active.

i can make this type menu by css skew transform but problem is that not support IE8. thats why i am choose this way change background image. i made Sprites image so via css i can change image position

you guys can suggest me if have any other way

i am trying here http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/vd28U/1/

Comment: I saw your jsfiddle implementation. There should be no space between #nav and .bg1 in your css definition, because they both belong to the same element. Same goes for the space between #nav and .bg2. Update your jsfiddle, and if you make progress, update the link to your jsfiddle.

Comment: thanks @msound. i updated but now my thing is how i can do that dynamical. mean when i rollover 1st line then bg2. 2nd li bg2 3rd li bg3 soemthing like that

Comment: @pagol, are you want to add class to li on mouse hover?

Answer (score 1):

I have understand you issue, i have made one jsFiddle for same http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/vd28U/2/

I have use data property for this, so can assign any dynamic class to UL

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" data-ul-class="bg1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-ul-class="bg2"><span>Products</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#nav li a").on("mouseover",function(){

        $("#nav").addClass($(this).data('ul-class')) 
});
$("#nav li a").on("mouseout",function(){
        $("#nav").removeClass($(this).data('ul-class'));  
});
```

Comment: thanks it work.. but i am thinking if i can do like li nt way then would be work for me perfectly. like when 1st li class current then UL class bg1 when 2nd li class current then ul class bg2 something like

Comment: @pagol you can also add current class to li at mouseover event.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/vd28U/5/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = $("#nav li").index($("#nav li.current"));  
    if (num > -1) { 
        $("#nav").addClass("bg"+num);
    }

    var cssClass = $("#nav").attr("class");
    $("#nav li a").on("mouseover",function(){
            var num = $("#nav li").index($(this).parent());
            $("#nav").removeClass(cssClass);  
            $("#nav").addClass("bg"+num);  
            showclass();
    }).on("mouseout",function(){
            var num = $("#nav li").index($(this).parent());
            $("#nav").removeClass("bg"+num);  
            $("#nav").addClass(cssClass);
            showclass();
    });
    showclass();
});

function showclass(){
    //debug
    $("#classinfo").html($("#nav").attr("class"));
}
```

Comment: cool this is work nicely but question can i add that condition also like when like if li class current then add bg1 bg2 bg3 etc. base one li nt child .. like if 1st li class current then bg1 , if 2nd li current then bg2

Comment: Something like this should work if I have undestood you well:
    `var num = $("#nav li").index($("#nav li.current"));`
    `if (num > -1) { $("#nav").addClass("bg"+num);}`

Comment: thanks @vitro.. it work nicely but one problem i found which is when i  rollover that time add class not replace. like bg3 bg4 ... i need to replace any idea  i updated http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/vd28U/4/

Comment: found another bug in my code. say like current class 3rd number li so if i rollover 4,5,6, no problem but when i rollove 1st LI  class come bg0 then after not back current li class anymore like bg3 (that was current)

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking if i can do like li nt way then would be work for me perfectly. like when 1st li class current then UL class bg1 when 2nd li class current then ul class bg2 something like . i will use that on wordpress. in wordpress easy to add to current class in active menu but so i am thinking like that way now li nt child way.